# PHP Loop - dealing with non-sequential iterations

Tags: php, loops, iteration, nonsequential

I have the following code - it produces a series of queries that are sent to a database:

```
$a = 'q';
$aa = 1;
$r = "$a$aa";
$q = 54;

while($aa <= $q){
$query  .= "SELECT COUNT(". $r .") as Responses FROM tresults;";
$aa = $aa + 1;
$r = "$a$aa";
}
```

The issue I have is simple, within the database, the number is not sequential.

I have fields that go from `q1` to `q13` but then goes `q14a`, `q14b`, `q14c`, `q14d` and `q14e` and then from `q15` to `q54`.

I've looked at **continue** but that's more for skipping iterations and hasn't helped me.

I'm struggling to adapt the above code to handle this non-sequential situation.  Any ideas and suggestions welcomed.

Comment: when db fields are named\numbered like that, its usually means its designed incorrectly

Comment: @Dagon - couldn't agree more - however, that's what I'm having to deal with :-(

Comment: @Dagon on my first job I inherited a db which only meaningful column names were `id`, the others were just `a`, `b`, `c`, ... etc. The same applied for table names. It was fun.

Comment: @zerkms well i inherited a db where every type was *text*. dates/ numbers everything ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have fields that go from `q1` to `q13` but then goes `q14a`, `q14b`, `q14c`, `q14d` and `q14e` and then from `q15` to `q54`.

```
for($i=1; $i<=54; ++$i) {
  if($i != 14) {
    echo 'q' . $i . "<br>";
  }
  else {
    for($j='a'; $j<='e'; ++$j) {
      echo 'q14' . $j . "<br>";
    }
  }
}
```

If you don’t need to execute the statements in order of numbering, then you could also just skip one in the first loop if the counter is 14, and then have a second loop (not nested into the first one), that does the q14s afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the columns from the table and test to see if they start with `q` (or use a `preg_match`):

```
$result = query("DESCRIBE tresults");

while($row = fetch($result)) {
    if(strpos($row['Field'], 'q') === 0) {
        $query  .= "SELECT COUNT(". $r .") as Responses FROM tresults;";
    }
}
```

Or build the columns array and use it:

```
$columns = array('q1', 'q2', 'q54'); //etc...

foreach($columns as $r) {
    $query  .= "SELECT COUNT(". $r .") as Responses FROM tresults;";
}
```